# fetch into array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object

i am trying to fetch into array of object.

i have : `arrayOfObject :`

```
0: {code: "YJYDWO1", route_id: 1}
1: {code: "YJYDWO2", route_id: 2}
2: {code: "YJYDWO3", route_id: 3}
3: {code: "YJYDWO4", route_id: 4}
4: {code: "YJYDWO5", route_id: 5}
```

I want to get object where route_id = 2 (example) using find or anything without for loop.

I do this using for loop:

```
for(let i=0; i<arrayOfObject.lenght; i++){
  if(arrayOfObjet[i].route_id == 2){
   // do what you want
}
}
```

that work but if i have 1 milion data object in arrayOfObject that take a large of time so i thing is better to do it using find or any method in javascript.

How to do this?

Comment: yes !, but i need other method like find hachset ...  after some search hachset is more better for filter large data in small time.  @Kinglish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like `Array.find`

```
let item = arrayOfObjects.find(x => x.route_id === 2)
```

But that is just hiding the for loop. Because iterating over the array is the only possibility to find the element.

To speed up the things a bit (if `route_id` are unique) you can `break` out of the loop once you found your element.

```
for (let element of arrayOfObject) {
  if (element.route_id === 2) {
    // Do your thing
    break;
  }
}
```

If you have to do many searches (and again `route_id` is unique) you probably should transform your array into a a map or something similar, so you can directly access the object by its key

```
// Do this once in the beginning
let m = new Map();
for (let e of arrayOfObject)
  m.set(e.route_id, e);


//Retrieve an element from the map
let x = m.get(2);
```